# How to make .Net wait for second response from webservice

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, response

I'm sending a XML request to a web-service, this web-service sends me a response that the request sent by me has been received and the test will be executed. The response include an (unique) identification string. The test will take up to a minute to execute. After the test has finished the web-service will send another response (without a initiating request from my side) containing the test results. 
I can't figure out how to tell .Net to wait for that second response from the web-service.

I've tried calling the service synchronous and asynchronous, but it looks like the problem is a received 200 message upon which .Net closes the stream. My guess is that I'm overlooking a fundamental detail how http requests and multiple responses work.

`response =  client.UploadString(uri, "POST", xml.ToString());`

`response = await client.UploadStringTaskAsync(uri, "POST", xml.ToString());`

I'm looking to gather the second response and eventually store that in a database. In the current situation the second answer is lost as it is never received on my side.

Comment: As far as I know HTTP, it is not allowed to send two distinct answer bodies as responses

Comment: How does the webservice send the response back?

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen: I get a response containing a XML message from the web-service.

Comment: So you have to make a second call? I mean the second response, the one you have to wait for, you say the web service *sends* that back, how does it do that?

Comment: Web technology allows you to keep a connection open and trickle information back to the client when you have it, but that is not a good way to handle web services. You only get to send headers once, etc. The reason why HttpClient or similar classes doesn't make it easy for you to consume a web service that works this way is that it is not the way to do it, so they didn't write the code to support it. If you want to consume a web service working this way, you're going to have to write the code to do it yourself, which will probably be a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too general, so it's really hard to answer exactly how to solve your problem. 
But from my knowledge, HTTP request from C# doesn't work as you mentioned.
Whenever you make a request, the server (web service) returns a single response (or an error) and that it. If you want the server (web service) notifies the client (your application), then the client needs  to subscribe to to the server somehow and handles the notification from the server

Comment: I was convinced HTTP works like @user1781290 said: One request will trigger one response from the web-server. According to the sequence diagram in the web-services documentation another response is sent without a request. Hence my question if I missed something. I'm investigating this further and opened a ticket with third party supplier.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody (and my own first thought) was right. It's impossible to do this the way the documentation suggested. After contact with my supplier they've told me to provide them with an url where **they** can post the second (async) response to.

In short:
- I need to provide my supplier with an url or emailadres to which they can respond.
- I send a request to their web-service.
- Depending on the status initial response a second response can be sent to the pre-configured response option at our side.